# Rails: "NoMethodError: undefined method `constructKDTree' for #<Class:0x00000104b1f760>"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi there I have 3 files in rails as follows:
1)Located at "app/controller/listings_controller.rb"

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController

  def index   
    #Construct kd Tree in memory
    @tree = Listing.constructKDTree;
    @tree.inspect
  end
```

2) Located at app/models/listing.rb

```
require 'kd_tree.rb'
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base

  def constructKDTree
    @contents = self.all

    @kdTree = KDTree.new(@contents) 

  end
```

3) Located at app/models/kd_tree.rb

```
class KDTree

  def initialize (db_listings)
    'Initializing Tree' 

  end

end
```

Now I'm trying to test the method implementation for `constructKDTree` so I went to my rails console and tried the following commands:

```
1.9.2-p290 :001 > @lc = ListingsController.new
 => #<ListingsController:0x00000104f3e288 @_routes=nil, @_action_has_layout=true, @_headers={"Content-Type"=>"text/html"}, @_status=200, @_request=nil, @_response=nil> 

1.9.2-p290 :002 > @lc.index
```

But I get this error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `constructKDTree' for #<Class:0x00000104b1f760>
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activerecord-3.2.1/lib/active_record/dynamic_matchers.rb:50:in `method_missing'
from /Users/AM/Documents/RailsWS/cmdLineWS/Businesses/app/controllers/listings_controller.rb:20:in `index'
from (irb):2
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
from /Users/AM/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined `constructKDTree` as an instance method on `Listing`. Thus the method is only available on instances of the class but nit the class itself.

Depending on what you actually want to achieve, you can make the method a class method like it's done in the following code, or you could create a new instance of the `Listing` class and call the method on the instance.

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.constructKDTree
    @contents = self.all
    @kdTree = KDTree.new(@contents) 
  end
end
```

However looking at the code you have there, you probably want to do the latter and create a new instance of the class:

```
listing = Listing.new
@tree = listing.constructKDTree
```

Comment: Hi Thanks. I come from a Java background and learning Ruby. So Class level methods are they like static methods in Java?

Comment: @banditKing: yeah, that's the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1):

This is a call to a *class* method:

```
@tree = Listing.constructKDTree
```

This is a definition of an *instance* method:

```
def constructKDTree
  @contents = self.all
  @kdTree = KDTree.new(@contents) 
end
```

You want `constructKDTree` to be a class method so you need to say this:

```
def self.constructKDTree
  #...
```